# Python NLTK parsing recursion error with custom grammar

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

I keep getting a recursive error when i try to run the code below

```
import nltk
from nltk import Nonterminal, nonterminals, Production, CFG
from nltk.parse import RecursiveDescentParser
from nltk.parse import ShiftReduceParser
from nltk.parse import ChartParser
from nltk.parse.generate import generate, demo_grammar
from nltk import CFG

grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP 
NP -> Det Nom | PropN | NP PP  
Nom -> Adj Nom | N
VP -> V NP | V S | VP PP
PP -> P NP
PropN -> 'Bill' | 'Bob' | 'He'
Det -> 'the' | 'a' | 'an' | 'some'
N -> 'bear' | 'squirrel' | 'park' | 'block' | 'table' | 'river' | 'dog' | 'dogs' | 'pasta'| 'anchovies' | 'restaurant' | 'fork'
Adj -> 'angry' | 'frightened' | 'furry'
V -> 'chased' | 'saw' | 'Put' | 'eats' | 'eat' | 'chase'
P -> 'on' | 'in' | 'along' | 'with'
""")

rd = RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)
sr = ShiftReduceParser(grammar)
cp = ChartParser(grammar)
s1 = 'Bill Put the block on the table'.split()
s2 = 'Bob chased a bear in the park along the river'.split()
s3 = 'Bill saw Bob chase the angry furry dog'.split()
s4 = 'an bear eat an squirrel'.split()
s5 = 'the dogs eats'.split()
s6 = 'He eats pasta with some anchovies in the restaurant'.split()
s7 = 'He eats pasta with a fork in the restaurant'.split()

for t in rd.parse(s1):
    print(t)
```

So far only the chart parser works but I would also like the other 2 parsers to work as well. i have a feeling the error has something to do with my grammar variable however i have not been able to find a fix.

Comment: What's the explanation for `VP -> V S`? (Eg. "Eats Bill saw the pasta" leading to the sentence "The squirrel eats Bill saw the pasta".) Perhaps you meant `VP -> V`?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think you should expect RD or SR parsing to work; the grammar (like the language) is ambiguous. Compare "Sue saw the man with a knife" and "Sue ate the pasta with a knife". In the first one, the PP is part of the NP and in the second one, it's part of the VP. But the grammar can't tell you that. Grammatically, they're identical. (There's a more amusing example in the NLTK book. Read that chapter. :-) )